# How to add a custom service into IOP cluster for "BigInsights basic service plan" on BlueMix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I have applied "BigInsights basic service plan" on Bluemix, and create a cluster. I want to add a custom service into the cluster. However, I find that there is no root or sudo permission on the Linux nodes to place my service image to Ambari resources stacks. Also, there is no "Actions -> +Add Service" button in Ambari admin UI to add a custom service.

So my question is how do you add a custom service into the cluster for the "BigInsights basic service plan"?

Answer (score 0):

Custom services are currently not supported on Bluemix BigInsights. Questions about features in the Bluemix offerings are best addressed on the IBM developerWorks Answers forum, where you can find [additional information](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/295532/how-to-add-a-custom-service-into-iop-cluster-for-b/?smartspace=bluemix) about this question.